# Is it possible to filter custom polygon layers in Mapbox Visual in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, polygon, mapbox-gl-js

Problem: I've drawn custom polygons in Mapbox Studio. I am using Mapbox Visual in Power BI and I would like to filter the polygons. I have given the Polygons ID values to differentiate them and to make it easier to filter them later on. I am able to display the custom polygons in Mapbox Visual in Power BI but I am unable to find out how to filter them according to these IDs. I really need help on how I can filter these custom polygons according to the IDs I have given them.